# Proyecto impresora fiscal Seniat

Tags: javascript, python-2.7

Muy buenas estoy haciendo sistema de ventas, se requiere conexion con impresora fiscal aprobada por seniat estoy usando un emulador de impresora la cual abre por el puerto com99 y realiza las operaciones al pedir un documento no fiscal, cuando opto por un ticket fiscal este emulador solo responde con un "muchas gracias". No se si alguien tendra mayor experiencia con este tema.

Como test use este codigo Para ir probando la conexion, ya estoy usando una impresora, el modelo PP9 Plus para sacar las facturas pero, aunque la conexion es establecida no manda los comandos a la impresora.

````
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tfhka import Tfhka
import sys
# msg = sys.argv[1]

printer = Tfhka()


def abrir_puerto():
    try:
        resp = printer.OpenFpctrl('COM3')
        if resp:
            print("Impresora Conectada Correctamente en: ")
        else:
            print("Impresora no Conectada o Error Accediendo al Puerto")
    except Exception:
        print("Impresora no Conectada o Error Accediendo al Puerto")
def facturaper():
        #Factura Personalizada
        printer.SendCmd(str("iR*21.122.012"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("iS*msg"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("i00Direccion: Ppal Siempre Viva"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("i01Telefono: +58(212)555-55-55"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("i02CAJERO: 00001"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("@COMMENT/COMENTARIO"))
        printer.SendCmd(str(" 000000030000001000Tax Free/Producto Exento"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("!000000050000001000Tax Rate 1/Producto Tasa General"))
        printer.SendCmd(str('"' + "000000070000001000Tax Rate 2/ Producto Tasa Reducida"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("#000000090000001000Tax Rate 3/ Producto Tasa Adicional"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("3"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("101"))
            
def documentoNF():
        #Documento No Fiscal
        printer.SendCmd(str("80$ hola mundo"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("80¡Esto es un documento de texto"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("80!Es un documento no fiscal"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("80*Es bastante util y versatil"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("80*Test de codigo"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("810Fin del Documento no Fiscal"))

def notaDebito():
        printer.SendCmd(str("iR*21.122.012"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("iS*Pedro Perez"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("iF*00000000001"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("iD*22/08/2016"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("iI*Z1F1234567"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("i00Direccion: Ppal Siempre Viva"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("i01Telefono: +58(212)555-55-55"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("i02CAJERO: 00001"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("BCOMENTARIO NOTA DE DEBITO"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("`0" + "000000003000000100Tax Free/Producto Exento"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("`1" + "100000005000000100Tax Rate 1/Producto Tasa General"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("`2" + "200000007000000100Tax Rate 2/ Producto Tasa Reducida"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("`3" + "300000009000000100Tax Rate 3/ Producto Tasa Adicional"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("3"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("101"))
def factura():
        #Factura sin Personalizar*
        try:
            printer.SendCmd(str("80$Hola mundo"))
            printer.SendCmd(str("@COMMENT/COMENTARIO"))
            printer.SendCmd(str(" 000000030000001000Tax Free/Producto Exento"))
            printer.SendCmd(str("!000000050000001000Tax Rate 1/Producto Tasa General"))
            printer.SendCmd(str('"' + "000000070000001000Tax Rate 2/ Producto Tasa Reducida"))
            printer.SendCmd(str("#000000090000001000Tax Rate 3/ Producto Tasa Adicional"))
            printer.SendCmd(str("3"))
            printer.SendCmd(str("101"))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

def welcome():
        printer.SendCmd(str("PH01Encabezado 1 "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("5001"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("PH08 Encabezado 8 "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("iR*J-123456789"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("iS*The Factory HKA "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("i01Línea Adicional 01 "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("i09Línea Adicional 09 "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("@Esto es un Comentario"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("000000100000001000Producto Exento "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("p-1000"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("!000000200000001000Producto General "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("k"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("p+1000"))
        printer.SendCmd(str('"'+"000000300000001000Producto Reducida "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("q-000001000 "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("#000000400000001000Producto Adicional "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("q+000001000"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("000000100000001000Producto Exento "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("k"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("#000000400000001000Producto Adicional "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("£000000400000001000Producto Adicional "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("$000000500000001000Producto Percibido "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("3"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("201000000002062 "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("211000000005100"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("122"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("199"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("i01 Línea Adicional 01"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("i09 Línea Adicional 09"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("PH91Pie de Ticket 01 "))
        printer.SendCmd(str("PH98Pie de Ticket 02"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("y1234567890128"))
        printer.SendCmd(str("810Fin del Documento no Fiscal"))
    
print('hecho')
abrir_puerto()
#facturaper()
documentoNF()
#welcome()
#factura()

    ```
````

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: mas detalles, todo es tan ambiguo como que no podemos dar respuestas claras

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: Ya hice las correcciones